# Puppet file resource need to check source is available and target is R/W

Tags: puppet

I have the following puppet class.

```
class vintela_monitor::keytab {
  file { '/etc/vasinst.key':
    ensure => 'present',
    source => '/auto/hosting-hard/QAS/creds/keytabs/vas_engit.keytab',
  }
}
```

I need to make sure the source is accessible (cd to that directory) and that the target file system is in read write mode before executing this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you not just host the `vas-engit.tab` on the Puppet Master and source it from there? Then you don't have to check its availability locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute **[mode](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#file-attribute-mode)** of the resource file

```
 file { '/auto/hosting-hard/QAS/creds/keytabs/vas_engit.keytab':
    ensure  => 'present',
    mode => '777',
 } 

  file { '/etc/vasinst.key':
    ensure  => 'present',
    source  => '/auto/hosting-hard/QAS/creds/keytabs/vas_engit.keytab',
    require => File["/auto/hosting-hard/QAS/creds/keytabs/vas_engit.keytab"],
  }
```

You can see more about mode and permessions [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm)